# How to do this theorem environment (this exact style)?

Tags: theorems, boxes

I'm writing a course support on latex and I was looking to my own old notes and came across this template for theorems and would like to implement it in my own course support.

[image]

Comment: This looks a lot like a use of `tcolorbox`. Look around p166 of the documentation, you should find examples very close to this.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Th\'{e}or\`{e}me}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[
    enhanced,
    title={Convergence domin\'{e}e -- version faible},
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    coltitle=black,
    colback=white,
    attach boxed title to top left={xshift=0.9cm,yshift=-2mm,yshifttext=-1mm},
    boxed title style={colframe=black,colback=white}
]
\begin{theorem}
Si $(f_j)_j$ est une suite de fonctions int\'{e}grables sur un intervalle $[a,b]$ qui converge
uniform\'{e}ment sur $[a,b]$ vers une fonction $f$ alors $f$ est int\'{e}grable sur cet intervalle
et
\[
    \lim_j \int_a^b |f_j(x) - f(x)| \,\mathrm d x = 0
\]
ce qui implique en particulier
\[
    \lim_j \int_a^b f_j(x) \,\mathrm d x = \int_a^b f(x) \,\mathrm d x.
\]
\end{theorem}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The integral symbol is different.